# How to create a fat jar with kafka source (to avoid submission-time dependency on a remote repo)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly, spark-structured-streaming

I'm writing a `Spark structured streaming` app that reads from and writes to `Kafka`. I've been trying to create a fat jar (using `sbt assembly`) for my spark application, that I can then submit to the spark cluster using the `spark-submit` script.

However, the application keeps failing with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:549)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceSchema(DataSource.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo(DataSource.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingRelation$.apply(StreamingRelation.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$21$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$21$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:533)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$21.apply(DataSource.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$21.apply(DataSource.scala:533)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:533)
```

**Questions**

1. In the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#deploying), I saw that the `spark-submit` script needs to be called with the    `--packages` parameter. What does this parameter do?
2. As far as I could understand, the `--packages` parameter downloads the specified package and its associated dependencies from the maven repo. If this is correct, is there a way to avoid this submission-time dependency on a remote repo and to a create a far jar that has all the dependencies embedded in it?

Following are the relevant portions of the build.sbt file:

```
  .....
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.10.1.0",
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % SPARK_VERSION % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % SPARK_VERSION,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % SPARK_VERSION % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % SPARK_VERSION,
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % SPARK_VERSION % "provided",
  ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % SPARK_VERSION).exclude("org.spark-project.spark","unused"),
  ......
```

**EDIT:** Here's my entire `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "abc"
organization := "com.myorg"
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
test in assembly := {}
version := "v1"

val SPARK_VERSION = "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.5.0",
  "com.metamx" % "java-util" % "0.27.10" % "provided",
  "com.twitter" %% "bijection-scrooge" % "0.9.4",
  "com.twitter" %% "finagle-thrift" % "6.35.0",
  "com.twitter" %% "util-collection" % "6.34.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.4",
  "io.druid" % "druid" % "0.9.1.1" % "provided",
  "io.druid" % "druid-api" % "0.9.1.1" % "provided",
  "jline" % "jline" % "2.9",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.3",
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.10.1.0",
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % SPARK_VERSION % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % SPARK_VERSION,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % SPARK_VERSION % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % SPARK_VERSION,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % SPARK_VERSION % "provided",
  ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % SPARK_VERSION).exclude("org.spark-project.spark","unused"),
  "org.clapper" %% "grizzled-slf4j" % "1.3.1",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "it,test",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.5",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.5"
)

// Ref: https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base
libraryDependencies += "com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "2.0.0_0.4.7" % "test"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Job Server Bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-jobserver/maven",
  "Typesafe repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")
)

val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
  javaOptions += "-Xmx2G",
  javaOptions += "-XX:+UseCompressedOops"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", "services", "io.druid.initialization.DruidModule") => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "codahale", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "google", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("io", "netty", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "inject", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "xml", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("META-INF", "io.netty.versions.properties") => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "apache", "avro", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "fusesource", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "slf4j", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "tachyonproject", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("scala", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.last
}

lazy val scalatest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4"
lazy val IntegrationTest = config("it") extend(Test)
def itFilter(name: String): Boolean = name endsWith "ITest"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(inConfig(IntegrationTest)(Defaults.itSettings) : _*)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies += scalatest % "it,test",
    parallelExecution in Test := false,
    javaOptions in Test += s"""-Djava.library.path=${baseDirectory.value / "src/test/resources/lib_pcap"}""",
    fork in Test := true,
    parallelExecution in IntegrationTest := false,
    testOptions in IntegrationTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(itFilter)))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the entire `build.sbt`? Can you check if the uber-jar has `KafkaSource` and `KafkaSourceProvider` inside?

Comment: HI @JacekLaskowski I've edited my question above to include the entire `build.sbt` file. Also, the uber-jar I'm creating does have both `KafkaSource` and `KafkaSourceProvider` classes inside. I verified this using `jar tf <uber-jar>` and grepping for these class names.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Adding another comment, since I couldn't highlight your name in the previous one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> needs to be called with the `--packages` parameter. What does this parameter do?

Places the jar and its transitive dependencies on CLASSPATH (and downloading them using Ivy if there are not available in the local artifacts repository).

> As far as I could understand, the --packages parameter downloads the specified package and its associated dependencies from the maven repo. If this is correct,...

That's correct.

> is there a way to avoid this submission-time dependency on a remote repo and to a create a far jar that has all the dependencies embedded in it?

Yes, indeed!

That's where [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) comes to stage (*no pun intended*). You should make sure that `build.sbt` is in proper shape and create a fat-jar.

Comment: HI @JacekLaskowski, thanks for the answer. I've shared my build.sbt file above but the Spark app in the uber-jar (created using `sbt assembly`) fails when I submit it to the Spark cluster. The error is mentioned in the question.